# HTML5 Canvas - Scrolling a map (made with a 2 dimensional array) using setTransform

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scroll

I'm making a 2D platformer with HTML5 Canvas. I have a map that's made using a 2 dimensional array. Ex:

```
var map = [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]
];
```

When the player moves, it updates the camera's position, and the map is scrolled accordingly (the camera dimensions are the same as the canvas, 800 by 500). This way, I can have a map as big as I want and I can keep the canvas the same size.

I've written a lot of code for this game, so I cut out everything except what's needed to show the problem. I'll format the jsFiddle code to show where all of the scrolling happens.

Now, to the problem.

The problem is that when the map scrolls, there's a 1px spacing between all of the tiles in the map.

How can I eliminate the 1px spacing between the tiles when the map scrolls?

I know it's a lot of code, but please please please try to help me out here! This problem is driving me nuts! Any ideas or solutions you can provide are much appreciated!

```js
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 500;

var framesPerSecond = 30;
var running = true;
var delta = 0;
var now;
var then = Date.now();
var counter = 1000/framesPerSecond;

const COLS = 48;
const ROWS = 10;
const TILE = 50;

var keyDown = {};

var gravity = 0.9;
var friction = 0.9;

var main = function(){
 now = Date.now();
 delta += (now - then);
 then = now;

 if(delta > counter){
  delta = 0;

//Set transformation back to normal
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  tick();

//Set transformation to camera location
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -player.camX, -player.camY);
    
  render();
 }

 requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

requestAnimationFrame(main);

var tick = function(){
 player.tick();
}

var render = function(){
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, COLS*TILE, ROWS*TILE);

 renderMap();
 player.render();
}

var tiles = {
 1:{
  color:"#1ac200"
 },

 2:{
  color:"#996633"
 }
};

var map = [
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
];

var renderMap = function(){
 for(var i=0; i<ROWS; i++){
  for(var j=0; j<COLS; j++){
//Making sure we only draw the portion of the map that's in the camera's view
   if(map[i][j] != 0 && j*TILE + TILE > player.camX && j*TILE < player.camX + 2*player.camOffsetX && i*TILE + TILE > player.camY && i*TILE < player.camY + 2*player.camOffsetY){
//Setting the color of the tile, then drawing it
        ctx.fillStyle = tiles[map[i][j]].color;
    ctx.fillRect(j*TILE, i*TILE, TILE, TILE);
   }
  }
 }
}

var player = {
 x:100,
 y:100,
 w:72,
 h:94,
 velX:0,
 velY:0,
 speed:3,
 dir:"right",
 canJump:false,
 crouching:false,

 boundingOffsetX:5,
 boundingOffsetY:5,

 camX:0,
 camY:0,
 camOffsetX:400,
 camOffsetY:250,

 tick:function(){
  this.velX *= friction;
  if(!leftCollision() && !rightCollision()){
   this.x += 2*this.velX;
  }

  if(37 in keyDown){
   this.dir = "left";
   if(!leftCollision()){
    if(this.velX > -this.speed && !this.crouching){
     this.velX--;
    }
   }
  }
  if(39 in keyDown){
   this.dir = "right";
   if(!rightCollision()){
    if(this.velX < this.speed && !this.crouching){
     this.velX++;
    }
   }
  }
  if(40 in keyDown){
   this.crouch();
  }else{
   this.crouching = false;
  }
  if(32 in keyDown && !this.crouching){
   this.jump();
  }

  topCollision();

  this.gravityHandling();
  this.checkCanvasEdgeCollisions();
  this.updateCamera();
 },

 render:function(){
  if(this.dir === "right"){
   if(!this.canJump){
    ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }else if(this.crouching && this.canJump){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000066";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }else{
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }
  }else if(this.dir === "left"){
   if(!this.canJump){
    ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }else if(this.crouching && this.canJump){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000066";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }else{
    ctx.fillStyle = "turquoise";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }
  }
 },

 jump:function(){
  for(var i=0; i<18; i++){
   if(this.canJump && !topCollision() && !this.crouching){
    this.velY -= 1;
   }
  }
  this.canJump = false;
 },

 crouch:function(){
  if(!this.crouching){
   this.crouching = true;
  }
 },

 gravityHandling:function(){
  if(!bottomCollision()){
   this.canJump = false;
  }

  switch(this.canJump){
   case true:
    this.velY = 0;
    break;
   case false:
    this.velY += gravity;
    this.y += this.velY;
    break;
   default:
    console.log("ERROR! Gravity is BROKEN!!!");
    break;
  }
 },

 checkCanvasEdgeCollisions:function(){
  if(this.x < 0){this.x = 0;}
  if(this.x + this.w > COLS*TILE){this.x = COLS*TILE - this.w;}
  if(this.y + this.h > ROWS*TILE){this.y = ROWS*TILE - this.h; this.canJump = true;}
 },

//This is where the camera's position is updated. It's updated according to the center of the player.
 updateCamera:function(){
  this.camX = this.x + this.w/2 - this.camOffsetX;
  this.camY = this.y + this.h/2 - this.camOffsetY;
  if(this.camX < 0){this.camX = 0;}
  if(this.camX + 2*this.camOffsetX > COLS*TILE){this.camX = COLS*TILE - 2*this.camOffsetX;}
  if(this.camY < 0){this.camY = 0;}
  if(this.camY + 2*this.camOffsetY > ROWS*TILE){this.camY = ROWS*TILE - 2*this.camOffsetY;}
 }
};


//Key detection and collisions from here on out.
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
 keyDown[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
 delete keyDown[e.keyCode];
});

var solidBlocks = {1:true, 2:true};

var collision = function(col, row){
 if(col < 0)
  col = 0;
 if(row < 0)
  row = 0;

 if(map[row][col] in solidBlocks){
  return true;
 }

 return false;
}

var topCollision = function(){
 var ty = Math.floor((player.y + player.velY + player.boundingOffsetY - 1) / TILE);

 if(!collision(Math.floor((player.x + 3*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty) && !collision(Math.floor((player.x + player.w/2 + 3*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty) && !collision(Math.floor((player.x + player.w - 3*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty)){
  return false;
 }

 player.velY = 0;
 player.y = ty * TILE + TILE - player.boundingOffsetY + 1;
 return true;
}

var bottomCollision = function(){
 var ty = Math.floor((player.y + player.h + player.velY - player.boundingOffsetY + 4) / TILE);

 if(!collision(Math.floor((player.x + 4*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty) && !collision(Math.floor((player.x + player.w/2 + 4*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty) && !collision(Math.floor((player.x + player.w - 4*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty)){
  return false;
 }

 player.y = ty * TILE - player.h + player.boundingOffsetY - 4;
 player.canJump = true;
 return true;
}

var leftCollision = function(){
 var tx = Math.floor((player.x + player.velX + player.boundingOffsetX - 1) / TILE);

 if(!collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE)) && !collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.h/2 + player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE)) && !collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.h - player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE))){
  return false;
 }

 player.x = tx * TILE + TILE - player.boundingOffsetX + 1;
 return true;
}

var rightCollision = function(){
 var tx = Math.floor((player.x + player.w + player.velX - player.boundingOffsetX + 1) / TILE);

 if(!collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE)) && !collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.h/2 + player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE)) && !collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.h - player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE))){
  return false;
 }

 player.x = tx * TILE - player.w + player.boundingOffsetX - 1;
 return true;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with non-integer positions of the transform. In the case where values for the positions are not integer they have to be anti-aliased, and the lines you see are due to this in combination with rounding errors; e.g. the lines doesn't perfectly overlap.

You can solve this by simply forcing the positions to integer like so (|0 at the end, of shift-0 converts the number to integer):

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -player.camX|0, -player.camY|0);
```

```js
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 500;

var framesPerSecond = 30;
var running = true;
var delta = 0;
var now;
var then = Date.now();
var counter = 1000/framesPerSecond;

const COLS = 48;
const ROWS = 10;
const TILE = 50;

var keyDown = {};

var gravity = 0.9;
var friction = 0.9;

var main = function(){
 now = Date.now();
 delta += (now - then);
 then = now;

 if(delta > counter){
  delta = 0;

//Set transformation back to normal
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  tick();

//Set transformation to camera location
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -player.camX|0, -player.camY|0);
    
  render();
 }

 requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

requestAnimationFrame(main);

var tick = function(){
 player.tick();
}

var render = function(){
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, COLS*TILE, ROWS*TILE);

 renderMap();
 player.render();
}

var tiles = {
 1:{
  color:"#1ac200"
 },

 2:{
  color:"#996633"
 }
};

var map = [
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
];

var renderMap = function(){
 for(var i=0; i<ROWS; i++){
  for(var j=0; j<COLS; j++){
//Making sure we only draw the portion of the map that's in the camera's view
   if(map[i][j] != 0 && j*TILE + TILE > player.camX && j*TILE < player.camX + 2*player.camOffsetX && i*TILE + TILE > player.camY && i*TILE < player.camY + 2*player.camOffsetY){
//Setting the color of the tile, then drawing it
        ctx.fillStyle = tiles[map[i][j]].color;
    ctx.fillRect(j*TILE, i*TILE, TILE, TILE);
   }
  }
 }
}

var player = {
 x:100,
 y:100,
 w:72,
 h:94,
 velX:0,
 velY:0,
 speed:3,
 dir:"right",
 canJump:false,
 crouching:false,

 boundingOffsetX:5,
 boundingOffsetY:5,

 camX:0,
 camY:0,
 camOffsetX:400,
 camOffsetY:250,

 tick:function(){
  this.velX *= friction;
  if(!leftCollision() && !rightCollision()){
   this.x += 2*this.velX;
  }

  if(37 in keyDown){
   this.dir = "left";
   if(!leftCollision()){
    if(this.velX > -this.speed && !this.crouching){
     this.velX--;
    }
   }
  }
  if(39 in keyDown){
   this.dir = "right";
   if(!rightCollision()){
    if(this.velX < this.speed && !this.crouching){
     this.velX++;
    }
   }
  }
  if(40 in keyDown){
   this.crouch();
  }else{
   this.crouching = false;
  }
  if(32 in keyDown && !this.crouching){
   this.jump();
  }

  topCollision();

  this.gravityHandling();
  this.checkCanvasEdgeCollisions();
  this.updateCamera();
 },

 render:function(){
  if(this.dir === "right"){
   if(!this.canJump){
    ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }else if(this.crouching && this.canJump){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000066";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }else{
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }
  }else if(this.dir === "left"){
   if(!this.canJump){
    ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }else if(this.crouching && this.canJump){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000066";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }else{
    ctx.fillStyle = "turquoise";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }
  }
 },

 jump:function(){
  for(var i=0; i<18; i++){
   if(this.canJump && !topCollision() && !this.crouching){
    this.velY -= 1;
   }
  }
  this.canJump = false;
 },

 crouch:function(){
  if(!this.crouching){
   this.crouching = true;
  }
 },

 gravityHandling:function(){
  if(!bottomCollision()){
   this.canJump = false;
  }

  switch(this.canJump){
   case true:
    this.velY = 0;
    break;
   case false:
    this.velY += gravity;
    this.y += this.velY;
    break;
   default:
    console.log("ERROR! Gravity is BROKEN!!!");
    break;
  }
 },

 checkCanvasEdgeCollisions:function(){
  if(this.x < 0){this.x = 0;}
  if(this.x + this.w > COLS*TILE){this.x = COLS*TILE - this.w;}
  if(this.y + this.h > ROWS*TILE){this.y = ROWS*TILE - this.h; this.canJump = true;}
 },

//This is where the camera's position is updated. It's updated according to the center of the player.
 updateCamera:function(){
  this.camX = this.x + this.w/2 - this.camOffsetX;
  this.camY = this.y + this.h/2 - this.camOffsetY;
  if(this.camX < 0){this.camX = 0;}
  if(this.camX + 2*this.camOffsetX > COLS*TILE){this.camX = COLS*TILE - 2*this.camOffsetX;}
  if(this.camY < 0){this.camY = 0;}
  if(this.camY + 2*this.camOffsetY > ROWS*TILE){this.camY = ROWS*TILE - 2*this.camOffsetY;}
 }
};


//Key detection and collisions from here on out.
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
 keyDown[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
 delete keyDown[e.keyCode];
});

var solidBlocks = {1:true, 2:true};

var collision = function(col, row){
 if(col < 0)
  col = 0;
 if(row < 0)
  row = 0;

 if(map[row][col] in solidBlocks){
  return true;
 }

 return false;
}

var topCollision = function(){
 var ty = Math.floor((player.y + player.velY + player.boundingOffsetY - 1) / TILE);

 if(!collision(Math.floor((player.x + 3*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty) && !collision(Math.floor((player.x + player.w/2 + 3*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty) && !collision(Math.floor((player.x + player.w - 3*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty)){
  return false;
 }

 player.velY = 0;
 player.y = ty * TILE + TILE - player.boundingOffsetY + 1;
 return true;
}

var bottomCollision = function(){
 var ty = Math.floor((player.y + player.h + player.velY - player.boundingOffsetY + 4) / TILE);

 if(!collision(Math.floor((player.x + 4*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty) && !collision(Math.floor((player.x + player.w/2 + 4*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty) && !collision(Math.floor((player.x + player.w - 4*player.boundingOffsetX) / TILE), ty)){
  return false;
 }

 player.y = ty * TILE - player.h + player.boundingOffsetY - 4;
 player.canJump = true;
 return true;
}

var leftCollision = function(){
 var tx = Math.floor((player.x + player.velX + player.boundingOffsetX - 1) / TILE);

 if(!collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE)) && !collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.h/2 + player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE)) && !collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.h - player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE))){
  return false;
 }

 player.x = tx * TILE + TILE - player.boundingOffsetX + 1;
 return true;
}

var rightCollision = function(){
 var tx = Math.floor((player.x + player.w + player.velX - player.boundingOffsetX + 1) / TILE);

 if(!collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE)) && !collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.h/2 + player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE)) && !collision(tx, Math.floor((player.y + player.h - player.boundingOffsetY) / TILE))){
  return false;
 }

 player.x = tx * TILE - player.w + player.boundingOffsetX - 1;
 return true;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```